# Why does a 240 volt outlet save money in electrical cost than a 120 volt outlet?

Tags: ac, three-phase

I live in the US and we have many outlets that run at 120 Volts.  I heard that for devices that support the 240 volt standard may not cost as much in electricity prices.

Can someone explain how by simply binding two 110 circuits together that is creates a money or electrical power savings when operating at 240 volts?

I vaguely know of AC "phases".  When a 240 circuit is created out of two 110 circuits, what happens w.r.t. the phases in the circuits?

Comment: Have you got an internet link to what you heard?

Comment: @Andyaka It's an internet forum / IRC, I'm not sure if that can be linked to.  I'll try to verify and show the link

Comment: @clabacchio: I don't know why this question was deemed to be off topic.  We have always discussed house wiring in the past, at least when it's somewhat about the theory behind it.  We don't want *How do I take the plastic part off the wire to get to the shiny stuff inside, then mount it somehow to make a outlet?*, but that's not what this is.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I mainly closed it because the question is about saving money by using this or that type of appliances, and it's not related to design whatsoever. It also doesn't provide any source for the statement that 240V is cheaper, so it makes it hard to answer directly. I saw that you provided a quite complete answer, but the question needs revision to be a better fit.

Comment: The question specifically asks about "electrical power savings" and the technical answer addresses that.  Closing it was a judgement mistake, of a sort that needs to not be repeated.

Answer (score 18):

Don't believe everything you hear.  In the US (and probably most other places too), you get billed for energy used.  Watts are Watts, whether you consume 1.1 kW by drawing 10 A from 110 V or 5 A from 220 V makes no difference to how much power you use or what you are charged.

Your house is run from a center-tapped transformer secondary.  Accross the ends, this secondary produces 220 V.  That means from the center tap to each end is 110 V.  All three wires are run into your house on big fat cables.  The center tap is grounded close to where it enters the house, which should also be close to the breaker panel.  This becomes the neutral for the 110 V circuits.  The other side for all 110 V circuits is one of the secondary ends, which are switched by the breakers.  220 V circuits, like for a electric dryer, water heater, or range, will be accross the two ends with a breaker that can disconnect each end.  While there are two breakers for such circuits, they will be ganged together in a single unit.  Sometimes this is obvious as they look like two breakers with a bar accrross the two switches so that they are always turned on or off together.  If one pops, it will also turn off the other.

The reason for going into all this detail is so that you can understand the difference between 110 V and 220 V circuits.  Both are fed by the same transformer secondary.  The primary can't tell which of the two halves of the secondary the power was drawn from, or if it was drawn as 220 V by using both together.

There is one advantage to 220 V circuits, which is why they exist at all.  With 220 V you only need half the current to get the same power as with 110 V.  Normally that doesn't matter much.  But, with high power appliances the current required at 110 V would require the wires to be uneconomically thick.

At really high currents, you might actually notice the power lost in the wires between the breaker panel and the appliance.  Those wires have some finite resistance, and the power lost in them goes with the square of the current thru them.  Therefore, appliances that require high current not only require expensive and thick wires, but cause more waste in those wires.  This is why for high current devices only, you go thru the trouble of using 220 V.  That requires half the current, and therefore would cause 1/4 of the power dissipation in wires of the same size.

In most installations however, wires are sized by the current they carry, regardless of the open-circuit voltage at the end.  The limiting factor is the amount of heat a wire is allowed to dissipate per unit length.  The electrical code specifies the maximum current for each wire gauge, based on all those factors and with a considerable amount of margin built in.  You don't houses *almost* catching fire at full load.  For example #10 copper wire is rated for 30 A if I rememer right.  So in reality, 220 V circuits allow for thinner wire, which costs less and is easier to work with.

So technically, devices that run from a higher voltage cause less wasted power in the wires.  That could be the basis of the claim that 220 V device cost less to operate, but it's far fetched.  The power lost in the wires is a tiny fraction of the power used by the device, so this is at best a very small advantage.  There are other advantages to using a lower voltage like 110 V.  This is why most things run from 110 V except that need unusualy high power.

Comment: The power dissipation in the wires will be reduced by a factor of four when switching from 110V to 220V *if the gauge remains constant*.  If the tolerable amount of power dissipation (heat generation) per lineal foot is constant, doubling the current will require doubling the wire *diameter* (quadrupling cross-sectional area).  Being willing to deal with 220V cuts by a factor of *four* the amount of copper required for the wires feeding something like a stove.  That's a major cost savings.

Comment: "Look at your breaker panel and you will see the breakers arranged in two colums. The two ends of the transformer secondary are run down the sides of the breaker panel, with each column switching that side only." That's a bit over-simplified. Since as you point out further down, you can insert double breakers for 220V branch circuits, the contacts down each side of the panel actually alternate between the poles of the incoming mains.

Comment: @supercat: You're talking about a capital (one-time) expense, while the OP is asking about the ongoing energy cost.

Comment: @DaveTweed: I would think that for most cable runs within a typical house, the cost of the electricity dissipated in the cable is likely to be far less of a concern than the heating caused by such dissipation.  While a larger cable in free air may be able to safely dissipate slightly more power per lineal foot than a smaller one, I think the rules for cable sizes in walls assume dissipation may be limited by external factors.

Comment: @Dave: Fixed about the breaker panel sides.

Comment: Most people aren't billed in watts (power) but rather watt-seconds/joules or killowatt-hours (energy).

Comment: @Phil: Yes, unfortunate choice of words fixed.